# How can I modify the main ember cli app tree of an ember app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am wondering if there is a way to modify the app tree. For example, lets say I have a component located in `app\components\my-component.js` . I want to totally ignore this component and not build it into the project. Is this possible?

I tried adding the following lines in my `ember-cli-build` :

```
var appTree = new Funnel(app.toTree(), {
    exclude: ['my-component.js']
});
```

But I believe that `app.toTree()` returns the tree after it has been minified and merged into a single `assets/my-app.js` . So it seems it is too late here.
 Is there anyway I can do this? Thank you.

Use case is, for example, if I have a single ember project, but I want to build it for different `targets` (whatever targets could be, let's say `french` and `english`) , I want to be able to completely exclude some files belonging to the other target, while building for another.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this from your `ember-cli-build.js`.
To do this you have to write an `ember-cli` addon. However you can use an in-repo-addon if you want to.

I think the right hook is [postprocessTree](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html#method_postprocessTree). And probably you want to filter on the `app` tree.